# How does a Dictionary reference works in C#

Tags: c#

A bit of code

```
    public class Test
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> a = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public int cnt => a.Count;

    public void Fn()
    {
        var b = a;
        b.Add(1, 2);
        b.Add(2, 2);
        b.Add(3, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(b.Count);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test test=new Test();
        test.Fn();
        Console.WriteLine(test.cnt);
    }
}
```

It prints 3 3 3, so basically what I don't get is that the b variable gets a reference to a, it wasn't a copy?

Comment: Think about this. Let's say that you have a house and the kitchen is painted blue. If a friend moves in with you, so your house is now their house, what colour is their kitchen? It's blue, right? Now, if you paint your kitchen yellow, what colour is the kitchen of your friend's house? Would the fact that it's yellow surprise you? Of course not, because that's how objects work. Programming objects are the same. There is only one dictionary in your code, referenced by two variables. If you change that one object via one reference, why would you not see that change via the other reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the b variable gets a reference to a, it wasn't a copy?

That's almost what happened. There's still one nit to pick in here.

References are like pointers-with-benefits to objects in memory. With this code, you have one Dictionary object in memory. It was created with the `new Dictionary<int, int>()` expression, and the rest of the statement assigns the **reference** (not the object) to the variable `a`. Next `a` is assigned to the variable `b`. This does mean a copy is made, but (and this is key) *only the reference is copied*. At this point `a` and `b` still refer to the **same object** in memory.

So we see `b` did **not** get a reference to `a`. It got a copy of the reference for the same object to which `a` was referring.

So instead of this, as suggested in the quote:

```
b => a(object)
```

or this, which is similar, but still not quite right:

```
b => a => object
```

what you actually end up with is this:

```
 b => object <= a
```

The distinction matters. Changing the object's state via the `a` variable will also be visible to `b` (and vice versa), because you're acting on the same object. But assigning a *new reference* to the `a` variable will not be visible on `b`, because `b` does not actually refer to `a` at all.

This is how it works for any type declared as a `class` (as opposed to a `struct`) — not just `Dictionary` — and the semantics for function calls are similar. The only exception is `string`, which has special handling in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Because a and b now share the same memory location, Dictionary is the reference type when you write var b = a; in public void Fn()   Basically, if you set reference equality, any change in b would be reflected in a, and any change in a would be reflected in b.

```
          **lets understand through reference type and value type through example of struct & class**
        
    
        deffierence-1
    
         - struct is value type
         - class is ref type
        
         
        deffierence-2
          
         - struct stored in stack
         - class stored in heap
        
         
        value hold there memory where they declared , but ref type hold a ref to an object in memory
        ex:
        
        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        c1.Id = 102;
        c1.Name = "Jhon";
        
        when you create an class object than ref variable (c1) will store in stack and actual obj will store in heap i.e (Id and name)
    
     deffierence-4 
    
         when socpe is lost value types are destroyed ,
          ref types only destroyed when ref variable is destroyed when scope is lost
        
        ex:
        
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            
                int i=0;
                if (i == 10)
                {
                    int j =20;
            
                    Customer c1 = new Customer();
                    c1.Id = 102;
                    c1.Name = "Jhon";
                }
            }
        
        • j(value type) will destroyed when if block is completed 
        • i(value type) will stay longer and destroyed when main() method is executed
        • c1(value type) will destroyed when if block is completed and object(ref type i.e Id and Name in customer object) it self will be destroyed later by garbage collector
          
deffierence-5
         copy operation struct to struct and ref to ref
        
        • you can copy struct to another struct operation of one struct will not affet antother struct because it is a value type
        
        ex:
            
        int i=10;
        int j=i; //copy of i to j wont affect to i 
        j = i + 1;//we copied from i and increment j by one
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0} && j = {1}", i, j);
        
        
        • when you can copy ref types  you only get a copy of ref variable , both of them pointing to the same object on the heap 
          operation on of one of the variable will affect another
        
        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        c1.Id = 101;
        c1.Name = "Mark";
        
        Customer c2 = c1; //only ref variable is copied to another ref variable however both of them pointing to same object in heap 
        
        Console.WriteLine("C1.Name = {0} && c2.Name = {1}", i, j);
        
            example : 
            
            
        
            public struct Customer
                {
                    private int _id;
                    public int Id
                    {
                        get { return _id; }
                        set { _id = value; }
                    }
            
                    private string _name;
                    public string Name
                    {
                        get { return _name; }
                        set { _name = value; }
                    }
                    
                    public Customer(int id, string name)
                    {
                        this._id = id;
                        this._name = name;
                    }
                    public void Print()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Id = {0} and Name = {1}", Id, Name);
                    }
                }
            
                    public static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
            
                        Customer c1 = new Customer(10,"Sam");                
                        Customer c2 = c1;
            
                        c1.Id = 20;
                        c1.Name = "James";
            
                        System.Console.WriteLine(c1.Id);
                        System.Console.WriteLine(c1.Name);
            
            
                        System.Console.WriteLine(c2.Id);
                        System.Console.WriteLine(c2.Name);
                        
                        //you can copy struct to another struct operation of one struct will not affet antother struct because it is a value type
                        
                        // now change struct to class in Customer and see the result
                    }
        deffierence-6

        structures can not have destructors but classes can have
        
        deffierence-7

        structures can not have default parameter less constructor but classes can have
        • because it make sense because struct does not have concept of object reference variable 
          and object that is why they don't need to have parameter less constructor and dystructors
        
        deffierence-8
        struct can not inherit from another class but class can , both struct and class inherit through interface
        
         Note :
         struct can not inherit from another struct, because struct are sealed type
         to prevent class from being inherited you can use sealed keyword
```